# how can add a created id to datepicker() with every click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to create a row of some inputs with unique id that they are created with every click on add another flight.like the image below in destina.us.
and It was removed with on click on remove icon.how I can add the created id to the codes related to Jquery UI datepicker until the calendar of inputs work correctly?
[image]

```
                         <div id="multiple">
             <div class="calendar-container">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-4 location-icon">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="origin" />
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-sm-4 location-icon destination-city">
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="destination" />
          </div>
             <div class="form-group col-sm-4 calendar">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="start day" id="date_start_multiple" />
        </div>
          </div>
           <div class="calendar-container">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-4 location-icon">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="origin" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 location-icon destination-city">
            <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Destination" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 calendar">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="start Day" id="date_start2_multiple" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="add-flight colorOrange add-anther-flight"><i class="fa fa-plus ml5"></i><span>add another flight</span></span>    
    </div>

                 $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('.add-anther-flight').click(function () {
                    addFlight();
                    });
        var i = 1;
        function addFlight() {
            $('#multiple').append(
               "<div class='flight'>" +
           "<div class='calendar-container'>" +
               "<div class='form-group col-sm-4 location-icon'>" +
                   "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='origin' />" +
              "</div>" +
               "<div class='form-group col-sm-4 location-icon destination-city'>" +
                   "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='destination' />" +
               "</div>" +
               "<div class='form-group col-sm-4 calendar calendar2'>" +
                   '<input type="text" class="form-control persianNumber" placeholder="start day" id="date_start_multiple-' + i + '"/>' +
               "</div>" +
              "</div>" +
      "</div>");
            i++;
        }

            $("date_start_multiple,date_start2_multiple").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date2 = $('#date_start').datepicker('getDate');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                    $('#date_finish').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                    //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                    $('#date_finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate',date2); 
                }

        });
    });
```

http://destinia.us/#_ga=1.109031490.1172383090.1484504028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some update of your code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga1pkuqq/1/)

So, first of all i'm add function where you send block container with datepicker and button for remove that block:

```
function initializeClicks($element) {
        $element.find(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function(date) {
                var date2 = $('#date_start').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                $('#date_finish').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                $('#date_finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
            }
        });

        $element.find(".remove-block").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    }
```

As you can see i'm added class on every date-picker input for easy initialization. 
Also, for generate id for datepicker, you can just use number of blocks and increment them for one

```
var index = $(".block").length + 1;
```

I hope that this helped you.